# Add 24 hours to a text time and calculate remain time with PHP

Tags: php

Good time
I have a text time like `2017-05-11 22:35:45`, I want to add 24 hours to this time and calculate remain time.
E.x:

1. Frist i have a time: `2017-05-11 21:00:00`
2. Second i want to add 24 hours to this time: `2017-05-12 21:00:00`
3. Third i whould like to calculate remain time to 2017-05-12 21:00:00 from current time (for example current time is 2017-05-11 22:10:00): `22 hours and 50 minutes`

So how can i do it using PHP ?

Comment: You should try first ... When you stuck, ask.

Comment: @HossamMagdy i think you don't know ;) i try it but can't find anything. Thnks for you unvote

Comment: You should post the code you tried. We have no idea who voted, either up or down. We can't & we shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
<?php
$input = '2017-05-11 21:00:00';

$plus_24hrs = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $input)->modify('+24 hour');
echo '+24hrs = ' . $plus_24hrs->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;

$remaining = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', time());
$diff = $remaining->diff($plus_24hrs);
echo 'to go: ' . $diff->format('%hh %im %ss');
```

Example output:

```
+24hrs = 2017-05-12 21:00:00
to go: 12h 24m 32s
```

Demo: https://eval.in/792876

Hope this helps.

Comment: `$remaining` could be `$now = new DateTime()`

Comment: Thank you @alistaircol ! that's very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I'wont post directly working code because looks like you need to learn more about PHP functions. Here you go. These 3 functions will do the job.
[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) [date-diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) [date_add](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

First you need to convert string to timestamp to make calculation and then you can calculate everything you want. Apples to apples. Never forget.

Answer (score 0):

Using [date_create](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) & [date_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

```
// Create date & add 24 hours to it
$datetime1 = date_create('2017-05-11 22:35:45');
date_add($datetime1, date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 day'));
// Create the ref date
$datetime2 = date_create('2017-05-11 21:00:00');
// Calculate the difference, & print a formatted version of it
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%r %d days %h hours %i minutes');
```

Comment: hank you @HossamMagdy ! that's very helpful but i can't upvote your post  because i need more score. Thanks

Comment: No problem @Amir . Glad to know this is helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 
    $starttime = strtotime('2017-05-11 21:00:00');
    $starttimeformat =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $starttime);
    echo "Current Time:"; 
    echo $starttimeformat;
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<br/>';
    $onedayadedtime_format = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+24 hours', $starttime));
    echo "End Time after adding 24 hours:"; 
    echo $onedayadedtime_format;
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<br/>';
    $currenttime = time();
    $currenttimeformat =  date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $currenttime);
    echo "Current Time:";
    echo $currenttimeformat;
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<br/>';

    $onedayadedtime_formatobject = date_create($onedayadedtime_format);
    $currenttimeformatobject = date_create($currenttimeformat);

    $datedifference = date_diff($onedayadedtime_formatobject , $currenttimeformatobject);


    echo "Time difference between dates "; 
    echo $onedayadedtime_format.' and '.$currenttimeformat;
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<br/>';
    echo "Hours: "; 
    echo $datedifference->h;
    echo '<br/>';
    echo "Minutes: "; 
    echo $datedifference->i;
    echo '<br/>';
    echo "Seconds: "; 
    echo $datedifference->s;
    echo '<br/>';
    echo "Year: "; 
    echo $datedifference->y;
    echo '<br/>';
    echo "Month: "; 
    echo $datedifference->m;
    echo '<br/>';
    echo "Days: "; 
    echo $datedifference->d;
    echo '<br/>';

    ?>
```